# Expected value of fractional part is less than 1/2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, equidistribution

(My apologies in advance; this is very open-ended but I ask leave to post regardless.)

I'm trying to recall a theorem on the fractional part of... some fairly natural class of sequences.  It showed that the expected value is not 1/2, as might be assumed, but rather some smaller value (perhaps around 0.4).  Unfortunately I can't think of what sorts of sequences these were, and that makes it quite hard to recall the theorem itself.

It was not about some contrived sequence like the Pisot/PV numbers.  If I can think of additional details I will edit them in or add them as a comment.

Comment: Was it related to simple continued fractions?

Comment: I know Pisot numbers but not PV numbers. Could you say what they are ?

Comment: @JeanMarie A [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) is a real algebraic number greater than 1 with all conjugates within the unit circle. (This may be what you call a Pisot number, not sure.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few possibilities come to mind including Benford's law.

Here is another: If $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $\frac {1}{X} - \lfloor \frac{1}{X} \rfloor$ is not uniform on $[0,1]$. For example, the density at $1/2$ is $\frac{4}{9} + \frac{4}{25} + \frac{4}{49} + ... = \frac{\pi^2}{2} - 4 \approx 0.9348.$ The expected fractional part of $1/X$ is $1-\gamma \approx 0.422784.$ See the  [Poussin proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poussin_proof).

See also the [Gauss-Kuzmin-Wirsing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin%E2%80%93Wirsing_operator).

Comment: Amazing.  The second result was the one I was thinking of.  As Didier Piau says, you are good at mind reading!

Comment: I'm tempted to add a mind-reading tag to this problem, and suggest a Mindreader badge be instituted.