# A property of polynomials in a paper by Rice

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

It [has been suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31273/1778) that a [mind-reading](/questions/tagged/mind-reading) tag be added. This is, unfortunately, a good candidate for such a tag...

I was reading a paper of Rice relating to a property of integer polynomials. The property required that $P$ be a monic polynomial of degree at least 2 such that $P(0)$ and $P(P(0))$ are nonzero. Also, perhaps less helpfully, the linear coefficient needed to be 0. (I believe these were all the conditions. Actually perhaps the $P(P(0))$ condition was only required if $P(0)=\pm1$.)

Unfortunately, I can't remember either the property or the paper! Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holy crap I think this is my paper.  The title is "Primitive Prime Divisors in Polynomial Arithmetic Dynamics" and is in the Journal *Integers* Vol 7(1) and also here: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~brice/ppd.pdf.

Comment: Of all the gin joints in the world, and of all the Rices...

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the title, your result, and half of your name...!

Comment: No problem, you made my day anyway. :D