# Benford and logarithms: are the fractional parts of the logarithm well-distributed on average?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, asymptotics, binomial-distribution, fractional-part

What, if anything, can be said about the distribution of
$$
X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \{\alpha\log k\}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a nonzero real constant and $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$? In particular, are their constants $c_1,c_2,e_1,e_2,e_3$ such that
$$
\limsup \frac{|X_n - c_1n|}{c_2n^{e_1}(\log^{e_2}n)^{e_3}}
$$
is positive and finite? (And are they absolute, as I would guess, or do they vary based on $\alpha$?)

Possibly related to: [Expected value of fractional part is less than 1/2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31273/1778), though I'm not making that claim of $c_1$.

Is this known to be an open problem? Should be be asking over on MathOverflow?

Comment: I should probably kick out a tag for [tag:reference-request].

Comment: Since $\alpha\log x$ is $\log_B x$ where the base is $B=e^{1/\alpha}$, any proof for one logarithm should work for all these functions (at least non-uniformly).